# jQuery .is(":visible") works in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery .is(“:visible”) not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337186/jquery-isvisible-not-working-in-chrome)

I am trying to get all of the visible items in an array. It's working fine in Firefox but not Chrome.

Here's my code:

```
$.each (t.config.promoInput, function (i, v) {
    var size = 0;

    $.each ($(v).find('option'), function (i, v) {
        $(v).show() // Show all options in <tt>$(v)</tt>.
            .not(':first-child') // Don't hide <tt>(All)</tt>.
            .not(':Contains("' + t.config.searchSpanInput.val() + '")') // Don't hide options that match the searchCriteria.
            .hide(); // Hide everthing that doesn't match or isn't (All).

        if ($(v).is(":visible")) {
            size++;
        }
    });
});
```

In Firefox size increments, whereas Chrome size stays equal to 0.

EDIT: :Contains is my own addition to the jQuery library. It is a case-insensitive version of :contains.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Note that you have to close both `each` code blocks

Comment: Also, I'm not sure but I think that referencing i and v in nested functions will access those in the parent scope, so no need to pass them?

Comment: @AramKocharyan no what's there is fine (if a little confusing). The inner "v" will be the succession of `<option>` elements that the outer iteration locates.  Note that it could be just `$(v).find('option').each(...)` instead of the `$.each()` version.

Comment: @Aram, they always refer to the closest defined variable with those names.. Since `i` and `v` are the parameters of the function those get used.. (*the innermost one*)

Comment: Also is the fact that you've got ":Contains" (instead of ":contains", lower-case) just a typo?

Comment: Does this work in IE?Are you working with `<option>` inside of a select?If that's the case, playing around with `<option>` tags is difficult and Browsers behave very differently

Comment: Using `v` both outside of the each and inside of it for two different elements can be very confusing. I can almost bet that Chrome is considering `<option>` elements as never `:visible`. I can't get fiddle to pull up to test.

Comment: If that is the case, and chrome considers options as `:not(:visible)` regardless of display property, you may need to use another way of checking visibility.

Comment: @KevinB check `css("display") === "none"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding and showing, (enable/disable) options is not well supported cross browser (disable/enable).  See this question for one possible solution to your issue: [jQuery disable SELECT options based on Radio selected (Need support for all browsers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877328/jquery-disable-select-options-based-on-radio-selected-need-support-for-all-brow/878331#878331)

Once you get the options trimmed down, you can then use length to get the size.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply check for the `"display"` property, if it's `"none"` than it's hidden, if it's `"inline"` than it is visible:

```
$.each (t.config.promoInput, function (i, v) {
    var size = 0;

    $.each ($(v).find('option'), function (i, va) {
        $(va).show() // Show all options in <tt>$(v)</tt>.
            .not(':first-child') // Don't hide <tt>(All)</tt>.
            .not(':Contains("' + t.config.searchSpanInput.val() + '")') // Don't hide options that match the searchCriteria.
            .hide(); // Hide everthing that doesn't match or isn't (All).

    });
    //add only visible options
   if ($(va).css("display") === "inline") {
        size++;
    }
});
```

Look here http://jsfiddle.net/gwbTm/2/ (i tested it with Chrome).
I think that setting the visibility of `<option>` is something that create problem with browsers (expecially wit IE)

Comment: This creates different results in Chrome and Firefox