# Empty tag elements and :visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the latest jquery version.(1.9.1)

I have an empty `span` element :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>

    <body> <span class="c"></span>

    </body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        alert($(".c:visible").length);
    </script>

</html>
```

- Chrome ( latest ver ) alerts `0`
- FF (latest ver) alerts `1`
- Ie (8) alert `0`

Why doesn't it alert`1` at chrome ? the element is not hidden.

*I can work around this by using filter and spit out all the `!display:none` but wanted to know if i'm doing anything wrong*

http://jsbin.com/urihov/2/edit

Comment: In FF and safari it is alerting 0

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe mmm..not to my testing....http://i.stack.imgur.com/fvl3j.jpg  (18.02)

Comment: FF 19.0.2 - displays "0"

Comment: @inser amazing. myne is 18.0.2 and it alerts 1.

Comment: From jQuery documentation:
`Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.`

Comment: FF: in jsbin it alerts `0` and in jsfiddle it alerts `1`, http://jsfiddle.net/hvf9R/

Comment: Check this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337186/jquery-isvisible-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: @undefined HA..HA... so it is now also depend on the app....great :-)

Comment: Check this one from different browsers:
http://jsfiddle.net/hvf9R/1/

It seems FF adds additional height (19px)

Comment: See also: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13132  Seems like it will be fixed in version 1.12/2.2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@inser is right a span is an inline element and only gains layout when it has content thus gaining the width and height of its content - in this case the width and height are 0 so not visible to the, if you add this css rule

```
.c {
  display: block;
}
```

you will see that the alert says 1 now since you have forced it to be a block element now thus inheriting the width of its parent and gaining layout.

hope it helps,

Cheers

Comment: Correct, but you need 0 width as well.
So use 
`width: 0;` or `float: left;`

Comment: actually if you add a width rule just to give it layout it is redundant since as block element via css it inherits the width of its parent which implies width: 100%;