# span hidden or not on webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check if a `<span>` is hidden or not on webkit browsers (chrome/safari).

Following this code:

```
<span>
    <div>TEST</div>
</span>
```

On chrome/safari, this span always appears to be hidden which is not.

Trying both `:hidden` and `:not(:visible)` {jq} or `(element.offsetWidth === 0 && element.offsetHeight === 0)` {js} give same result.

Only setting some kind of css padding to the span seems to get rid of this behaviour, but it's not acceptable in the special case i'm working on.

I'm aware there are some relative tickets on jquery tracker but i cannot figure an adequate workaround.

Could you help me on this one?

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qHtdd/)

Comment: Can't have div's inside spans

Comment: Your span contains a <div> tag - which it shouldn't. When you inspect the div it states that it has height and width of 0, ergo it's not visible.

Comment: I'm aware of not valid html code but unfortunately this code is not mine. So, is there any alternatives?

Comment: @roasted Maybe not a great way but `console.log($('#myspan').css('visibility'));`

Comment: @Zenith problem here is if span have display set to none

Comment: @roasted Ah You're correct. Seems like a webkit bug :/ I looked around and saw some other mentions of this problem too

Comment: @Zenith Yes it is, same happen with <br />

Comment: @roasted Yep, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337186/jquery-isvisible-not-working-in-chrome. I think you've got the good answer mentioning display block

Comment: @Zenith i didn't saw this link, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `display:block` on the `span`, it seems to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/eREQJ/1/

Comment: display:block looks like not so bad alternative thx  Fixed your jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/eREQJ/1/

Comment: Yeah, just noticed it wasn't quite working the way I'd thought heh. But at least it eventually helped. :)

Comment: In fact, i think its a good workaround, just have to set css display to these specific span then reset it when checked

Comment: I'd agree. I've definitely seen some weirdness before on any display:block element nested in a display:inline element.

Comment: Thx mookamafoob for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = document.getElementById('myspan');
if(element.getAttribute('visibility') == 'hidden'){
    console.log('true')
}else{
    console.log('false')
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qHtdd/2/)