# Difference between :hidden and :not(:visible) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I know that both jQuery selectors match elements that are not visible (`width` or `height` equal to 0, `display: none`, parent with `display: none`), and I believe it is implied they should yield the same result in [the](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) [docs](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

For readability reasons, I would rather use `:hidden` but I want to know:

- Are there any potential pitfalls that I should consider?
- Will I always get the exact same result?
- Which option has better performance?

Comment: They're both the same thing, `:not` can be used for other things like `:checked`

Comment: I agree with you on the "readability", `:hidden` is better/easier to comprehend to me than the negative selector of `:not(:visible)` - and should actually be imperceptibly but slightly faster.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

- **EDIT 3/22/2016: add to answer re: jQuery 1.12/2.2 and 3.0** (*see end of answer)
- **EDIT 3/8/2016: enhance answer**

---

Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:

- They have a CSS `display` value of `none`.
- They are form elements with `type="hidden"`.
- Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
- An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

Elements with `visibility: hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered to be visible, since *they still consume space in the layout*. During animations that hide an element, the element is considered to be *visible until the end of the animation*.

Elements that are not in a document are not considered to be visible; jQuery does not have a way to know if they will be visible when appended to a document since it depends on the applicable styles.

The `:hidden` selector is the opposite of the `:visible` selector. So, every element selected by `:hidden` isn't selected by `:visible` and vice versa.

During animations to show an element, the element is considered to be *visible at the start of the animation*.

How `:hidden` is determined was changed in jQuery 1.3.2. An element is assumed to be hidden **if it or any of its parents consumes no space in the document**. *CSS visibility isn't taken into account*

---

**Clarification** "width or height equal to 0," - not strictly true as some browsers (opera) reports less than 0 in some instances so jQuery uses `<=0` internally.

1. Are there any potential pitfalls that I should consider?
2. Will I always get the exact same result?
3. Which option has better performance?

1: "Pitfalls" other than obvious of which I am unaware of any, is somewhat subjective.  I say this as I try to avoid "negative" tests in code (not x or !x type checks) as equality checks are more intuitive for my brain to understand.

2: Yes, the result should be the same

3: Re: Performance
Difference between: RE: 1.10.1 version

Visible condition check uses the not hidden internally:

```
jQuery.expr.filters.visible = function( elem ) {
    return !jQuery.expr.filters.hidden( elem );
};
```

So it could be said that strictly speaking "hidden" should be more efficient avoiding the "not" condition.

Internally, jQuery uses a "right to left" selector so the selector will make more of difference in some cases.

For performance, use

```
$(selector).filter(':hidden')
```

or

```
$(selector).not(':visible')
```

rather than either

```
$('selector:not(:visible)')
```

or

```
$('selector:hidden')
```

Why is this? `:hidden` is a jQuery extension and therefore cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. (see the right to left parsing of the Sizzle engine for how it will occur)

### Forms/format of the selector

This is because for the `$('selector:hidden')` form, it will select (walking the DOM)

1. all hidden elements first,
2. then select those matching the selector from that set.  It would be preferred to **match the selector first**, then filter those in that set that are hidden.

internal "isHidden" function: (jQuery 1.10.1)

```
function isHidden( elem, el ) {
    // isHidden might be called from jQuery#filter function;
    // in that case, element will be second argument
    elem = el || elem;
    return jQuery.css( elem, "display" ) === "none" || !jQuery.contains( elem.ownerDocument, elem );
}
```

Used for example in the `.showHide` internally such as:

```
if ( elem.style.display === "" && isHidden( elem ) ) {
```

Worth noting that the "hidden" attribute in `defaultPrefilter` is:

```
hidden = elem.nodeType && isHidden( elem ),
```

### Special note on *style*:

Setting an elements CSS as:

```
document.getElementById("hide-me").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

is very fast.

You can also detect this very fast:

```
document.getElementById("hide-me").style.visibility  === "hidden";
```

Remember though that the element still takes up space whereas `document.getElementById("hide-me").style.display = "block";` does seem to make it visible but keep in mind that some *PARENT might NOT be visible* thus the element might still be considered "hidden" - and jQuery does detect this (see above)

Additional reference: https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

### Additional information re: jQuery 1.12/2.2 and 3.0 3/22/2016 edit

There have been some significant speed improvements in these versions.

- Reference this post: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2042
- Related reference: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/issues/315#issuecomment-74336936

This change can yield up to **1600% speed improvements** wow! By taking advantage of caching when possible - which from what I have observed often occurs with these selectors.  Test your pages with both if you have need for improvement or concerns in this area and use cases if heavily utilized within your pages.

You should see improved performance with `.show()` and `.hide()` as a result.

jQuery 1.12+ and 2.2.0+ and 3.0 modify the meaning of the `:visible` and `:hidden` filters. Elements will be considered `:visible` if they have layout boxes.  This includes those with zero width and/or height. For your selectors beware of the count.  Examples:  inline elements with no content and `br` elements will now be selected by the `:visible` filter.

Page Markup examples:

```
<div>
</div>
<span></span>
<br />
<p>
</p>
```

With the following sector:

```
var visibleElementCount = $('body').find(':visible').length;
```

- In jQuery 1.11.1 and 2.1.4 return value 2 for `visibleElementCount`
- In jQuery 1.12+ and 2.2.0+ and 3.0 you’ll obtain 4 for `visibleElementCount`.  Test when you rely upon this fact as it may be a breaking change for your pages.

Comment: Does Sizzle actually enumerate simple selectors when walking RTL? Just curious - all I know is that a native CSS selector engine enumerates compound selectors RTL and parses each one atomically because there's no reason for it to always start with the rightmost simple selector.

Comment: Oh, I misread. I'm guessing `selector` represents the entire compound CSS selector, and `:not()`/`:visible`/`:hidden` respectively would operate on the elements that match that set. Either way, it probably doesn't matter very much. Implementation details and all.

Comment: The difference is normally not significant however IF you have performance issues, a complex selector with several classes, children etc. can have a negative impact. Shorter might be better but shorter (complex) selectors are not faster: Example `$('#myid>.child1>.gchild>.ggchild:not(".fred"):not(:hidden)')` - especially where `.child1`etc have many peers in a large DOM.

Answer (score 6):

Hmm.. interesting :)

```
:hidden = :not(:visible) = css selector 'display: none;'
```

**Now some other facts:**

css selector `'visibility: hidden;' = 'opacity: 0;' = not display` in page but `occupy space`.

css selector `'display: none;' = not showing in page` and also `not occupying space`.

by jQuery you can play with element who have `'display: none'` style

**HTML Example:**

```
<input type='text' class='display' value='Display' />
```

**CSS Example:**

```
.display{
  display: none;
}
```

**Check:**

```
alert($('.display').val());// Display

$('.display').val('Hello');

alert($('.display').val());// Hello
```

Answer (score 3):

They both will act in the same way with no conceivable difference.

Both will get you elements that take up space on the page. This includes elements with the `visibility: hidden` property.

[jsfiddle showing this in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/jWZxw/)