# On click check if there are elements in a form which are with display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a form in which I have hidden some inputs when a button is clicked. I have a validation code, which runs through every input and prints an error message if there are empty inputs. But in order to submit the form I have to fill every element, including the invisible ones, because the code is printing the message although I have filled all visible elements.

Here is the code for the validation

```
$('button.submit-first').click(function() {
    var emptyElements = $('form.registration-form div.first-part :input').filter( function() {
        return this.value === '';
    });

    if (emptyElements.length === 0)
    {
        $('p.red').css('display', 'none');
    } 

    else
    {
        $('p.red').css('display', 'block');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('div.row').offset().top}, 800);
    }
});
```

I can't seem to figure out how should I go through the inputs and if there are invisible ones just skip them and check the visible ones.

Comment: this might help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17426800/17447

Comment: Much appreciated, I found my mistake and then found a better way to do it with that article. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add ":visible" to the input to only validate those.

```
$('button.submit-first').click(function() {
    var emptyElements = $('form.registration-form div.first-part :input:visible').filter( function() {
    return this.value === '';
});
```