# Change visibility of another element if display none in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, hidden, display

I need to change the display property of another element if a specific element has `display:none`.

```js
if ($("#first-layer").css('display') === 'none') {
  $("#second-layer").removeAttr("visibility");
}
```

```css
#second-layer {
  color: black;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  visibility: hidden; // here I have to change by jQuery
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div id="first-layer">
    <div id="header-elements">
      <div id="img-rain" class="animated fadeIn" class="img"><img src="img/img.png"> </div>
      <div id="typed-strings" class="text">
        <span class="animated fadeInUp" id="typed"></span>
        <br/>
        <span class="description animated fadeIn">Your weather in one place</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="typed-strings">
    </div>
    <div class="start">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg responsive-width button-                       bg-clr animated fadeIn">Get Started</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="second-layer">123</div>

</header>
```

I tried solutions from the internet but they didn't work.

Comment: visibility: hidden;  is not an attribute so you cannot target it with removeAttr

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not do anything at the moment but you will likely have an easier time with

```
if ($("#first-layer").not(":visible")) { // or .is(":hidden")
  $("#second-layer").show();
}
```

or

```
$("#second-layer").css({visibility:visible});
```

since CSS declarations are not attributes

More about detection here
[Difference between :hidden and :not(:visible) in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425543/difference-between-hidden-and-notvisible-in-jquery)

Comment: Thank you very much :) 

Result:
I set in css for second-layer display: none and in JS i put this:

        if ($("#first-layer").is(":hidden")) 
        {
            $("#second-layer").css('display', 'block');
        }

Answer (score 1):

Using [`jQuery( ":hidden" )`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

```
// if selector is none then
if($('#first-layer').is(":hidden")){

     // alter second-layers visibility
     $('#second-layer').css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```