# How to find the input value according to the display : block in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

1- I have multiples tr in a table, every td in tr has 2 spans and an input has a value, every span maybe it will be display:block or display:none dynamicly.

2- I want that i get the value of the input in the td which has 2 spans with display: block, in my exemple the input result must be select is : input3 because it's the first td has 2 span with display:block.

3- This is my table exemple:

```js
var inputValue = $('.span1:visible:first, .span2:visible:first')
  .parent()
  .parent()
  .find('input').val();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input value="input1">
      <span class="span1" style="display:none">span1</span>
      <span class="span2" style="display:block">span2</span>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input value="input2">
      <span class="span1" style="display:block">span1</span>
      <span class="span2" style="display:none">span2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input value="input3">
      <span class="span1" style="display:block">span1</span>
      <span class="span2" style="display:block">span2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input value="input4">
      <span class="span1" style="display:block">span1</span>
      <span class="span2" style="display:block">span2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

4- i wrote this code yo fo that but i know it's wrong :

```
 <script>
 var inputValue = $('.span1:visible:first, .span2:visible:first').parent().parent().find('input').val();
 </script>
```

5- any help jquery code can do what i want please?

Comment: Please clarify if you actually DO want to as you say find those with the specific style attribute`"display:block"` as opposed to a visible set of two sibling spans as these are quite different things.

Comment: If something changes such as the classes or visibility on the `<span class="newspan1" style="display:inline-block"> </span>` does that matter or how would that effect your question/result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a siblings selector or using a filter(function) that checks siblings length

```js
var inputValue = $('.span1:visible ~ .span2:visible').siblings('input').val();
console.log('Using siblings selector: ', inputValue)

// OR
var inputValue2 = $('td input').filter(function(){
    return $(this).siblings('span:visible').length === 2;
}).val();
console.log('Using filter: ', inputValue2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input value="input1">
      <span class="span1" style="display:none">span1</span>
      <span class="span2" style="display:block">span2</span>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    
    <td>
      <input value="input2">
      <span class="span1" style="display:block">span1</span>
      <span class="span2" style="display:none">span2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input value="input3">
      <span class="span1" style="display:block">span1</span>
      <span class="span2" style="display:block">span2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input value="input4">
      <span class="span1" style="display:block">span1</span>
      <span class="span2" style="display:block">span2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Fun to guess intent right?  So many options depending upon that...

Answer (score 0):

First you have a syntax error in your markup, I have the extra line removed.

You can use a filter to get the candidate elements and then get the first one of those or use a number of other methods, here are some of those:

Supplemental to this related to  visibility:https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426800/125981

```js
let mytds = $('table').find('tr').find('td');
var myinput = mytds.filter(function(index) {
  return ($(this).find('.span1:visible').length + $(this).find('.span2:visible').length) > 1
}).first();

let iv = myinput
  .closest('td')
  .find('input').val();
console.log(iv);

let iv2 = mytds.filter(function(index) {
  return $(this).find('.span1').css("display") == "block" && $(this).find('.span2').css("display") == "block";
}).first().closest('td').find('input').val();
console.log(iv2);


let iv3 = mytds.filter(function(index) {
  return ($(this).find('.span1, .span2').filter(":visible").length == 2);
}).first().closest('td').find('input').val();
console.log(iv3);

let iv4 = mytds.children('.span1:visible ~ .span2:visible')
  .first().siblings('input').val();
console.log(iv4);

let iv5 = mytds.children('.span1:visible ~ .span2:visible')
  .siblings('input').first().val();
console.log(iv5);

let iv6 = mytds.children('.span1:visible ~ .span2:visible')
  .siblings('input').eq(0).val();
console.log("iv6:", iv6);

let iv7 = mytds.children().filter('.span1:visible ~ .span2:visible')
  .siblings('input').val();
console.log("iv7:", iv7);

let iv8 = mytds.has('.span1:visible').has('.span2:visible').find('input').first().val();
console.log(iv8);

let iv9 = mytds.has('.span1:visible').has('.span2:visible').find('input').val();
console.log(iv9);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input value="input1">
      <span class="span1" style="display:none">span1</span>
      <span class="span2" style="display:block">span2</span>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input value="input2">
      <span class="span1" style="display:block">span1</span>
      <span class="span2" style="display:none">span2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input value="input3">
      <span class="span1" style="display:block">span1</span>
      <span class="span2" style="display:block">span2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input value="input4">
      <span class="span1" style="display:block">span1</span>
      <span class="span2" style="display:block">span2</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I made a good number of assumptions regarding the question with this answer as it stands now.

Answer (score 0):

Use each function

```
 $(".span1").each(function(){
    // get style attribute value of span class span1
    var style = $(this).attr("style");
    // get style attribute value of span which is right after class span1
    var style_next = $(this).next().attr("style");
    // if both styles are display:block
    if(style == "display:block" && style_next == "display:block"){
        // variable value is set to value of input which is previous to span1 element
        var value = $(this).prev().val();
        // do whatever you need with that value
        console.log(value); 
    }   
 });
```

Comment: this breaks in may ways when conditions change - but it is not "wrong" as it stands except of course the `.each` gets all not just the first one as you have it.

Comment: as I see it, it gets the first one as there is ".span1" not "span", also I wouldn't recommend using inline styling. And yes it breaks if conditions change, I was posting is as an idea of "how to"

Comment: IF you test it against the actual HTML in the OP;s post you get `input3
input4` as output

Comment: "input3 because it's the first" from the OP's post is where I got the "first one" interpretation of my comment