# jQuery review DOM and react

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of DIVs which are the feed in a portfolio which has a filtering system which shows and hides the DIVs - this works well - I am adapting this system to look at the DIVs that match the filter clicked on and then style them with a new class with jQuery. CSS `nth-of-type` does not work, as it recognizes the hidden divs and thus messes up my custom layout, so I need a reliable way of checking the list of DIVs and applying the new class ONLY to those which do not have the inline style `"transform: scale(0.001)"` applied to them - this inline style is applied by the filtering system which I don't want to mess around with - so am looking for a way of adding a new class to the DIVS which don't have `"transform: scale(0.001)"` applied each time the filter buttons are clicked.

The classes I want to add are "itemPOS1" to the first div without the transform applied, then "itemPOS2" to the 2nd, etc etc... so the list of DIVS below would look like this on initial load:

```
<div>Project 1</div>
<div>Project 2</div>
<div>Project 3</div>
<div>Project 4</div>
<div>Project 5</div>
```

Then after clicking on a filter the list could look like this:

```
<div>Project 1</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 2</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 3</div>
<div>Project 4</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 5</div>
```

In which case - the list would then look like this once I have added the new classes to those DIVS which are suitable:

```
<div class="itemPOS1">Project 1</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 2</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 3</div>
<div class="itemPOS2">Project 4</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 5</div>
```

So, in the front end - the user would just see "Project 1" and "Project 4"....

I cant seem to get this to work well - I was using:

```
$('div:visible:eq(0)').addClass('itemPOS1');
$('div:visible:eq(1)').addClass('itemPOS2');
$('div:visible:eq(2)').addClass('itemPOS3');
$('div:visible:eq(3)').addClass('itemPOS4');
```

but its not reliable as sometimes it applies classes to DIVs which have the transform: scale(0.001) applied and thus makes the rendering of the projects wrong as the class names get added incorrectly. I was hoping to find a way to only apply the adding class logic to those divs which did not have "transform: scale(0.001)" applied to them...

I also want to add itemPOS1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 to each 5 DIVs that dont have the inline transform applied - so for example - the 6th DIV that should have the class applied should get itemPOS1 not itemPOS6

Any thoughts?

In essence looking for:

if div does not have transform: scale(0.001) then add class itemPOSX

X starting at 1 for 1st div, then 2 for 2nd... up to 5th, then 6th div has itemPOS1, div 7 has itemPO2 etc...

```js
$('div:visible:eq(0)').addClass('itemPOS1');
$('div:visible:eq(1)').addClass('itemPOS2');
$('div:visible:eq(2)').addClass('itemPOS3');
$('div:visible:eq(3)').addClass('itemPOS4');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>basic set</h2>
<div>Project 1</div>
<div>Project 2</div>
<div>Project 3</div>
<div>Project 4</div>
<div>Project 5</div>
<h2>test set filtered:</h2>
<div>Project 1</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 2</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 3</div>
<div>Project 4</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 5</div>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `transform: scale(0.001)` over other methods to show/hide elements? Also, can you update your question with a working example of the problem.

Comment: Do you need to apply the CSS effect transform: scale for visual design purposes or is this just a way for you to differentiate between certain divs?

Comment: @j08691 - The existing filtering system is doing that - I dont want to change that system, im just adding some bits to work after the filtering happens. Cant really show the working example as its not a public solution at this time.

Comment: @SJacks - Im not using the transform: scale for anything - the current filtering system uses that to hide the none relevant DIVs after a filter button has been clicked on. I was just thinking the most reliable way for me to ONLY apply my itemPOSX classes was to apply them to the DIVS which did not have the transform:scale applied to them as an inline style

Comment: I added your basic set of code as  snippet - feel free to update it with the "buttons" or whatever is triggering the jQuery in it - I just put it in a "run" and did not add any relevant CSS etc.

Comment: Thanks - I think i'm making this confusing and harder than it should be... All I am looking for is the jquery to look at the list of DIVS and add itemPOSX class to those in order which dont have the inline transform:scale style applied.

Comment: Yep, see my answer with some additional comments related to that style and what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your instance `:visible` won't work as technically it is still not hidden, just *really* small. use `not()` instead.

**Update** from your comment I'm assuming you want to reset the count after 5. For that we can use the [modulo (or remainder) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to get the remainder of a division.

```js
let maxPos = 5;


//Select all divs that don't contain your transform style and iterate
//The selector would also work with querySelectorAll natively
$("div:not([style*='transform: scale(0.001)'])").each(function(idx){
  //If maxPos > 0 use the modulo operator to get our position index
  //otherwise don't reset
  let classIdx =  maxPos > 0 ? idx % maxPos + 1 : idx;
  //Add the class dynamically based off the index
  $(this).addClass("POS"+classIdx)
  //Or if you want to one line it:
  //$(this).addClass("POS"+(maxPos > 0 ? idx % maxPos + 1 : idx));
});
```

```css
/*Just to display the added class name*/
[class^=POS]::after {
  content: 'Class: ' attr(class);
  font-size:0.75em;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-left: 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Project 1</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 2</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 3</div>
<div>Project 4</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 5</div>
<div>Project 6</div>
<div>Project 7</div>
<div>Project 8</div>
<div>Project 9</div>
<div>Project 10</div>
```

For more info see [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and the [`not()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

Comment: Thanks - this looks almost perfect - last thing I need is that I only have x5 classes to be added to each 5 DIVs - so, for the 6th DIV tht doesnt have transform:scale(0.001) applied it should have POS1 and not POS6 - can you advise how to do that with your approach?

Comment: Perfect - thanks - this is just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (check the console):

Explanation :

1. we set a counter variable starting at 1
2. we iterate every `div`
3. we check for div's NOT having the specified style,when found we apply the required class using the counter value and increment the counter by 1.
4. when counter reaches our upper limit (5),we set it back to 1.

```js
const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div")
let counter=1;
allDivs.forEach(div=>{
  if (div.style.transform !== "scale(0.001)" ) {
  if(counter<6){
  $(div).addClass('itemPOS' + counter);
  counter++
  }else{
  counter=1;
  $(div).addClass('itemPOS' + counter);
  counter++
  }

  }
  console.log( "class is : " + div.classList[0] + " and style(transform) is : " + div.style.transform )

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div>Project 1</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 2</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 3</div>
<div>Project 4</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 5</div>
<div>Project 6</div>
<div>Project 7</div>
<div>Project 8</div>
<div>Project 9</div>
<div>Project 10</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off: these are not "hidden" as such.
Visible vs hidden reference: [Difference between :hidden and :not(:visible) in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17425543/125981)

they have this: [image: styles applied]

### What I did (roughly)

Here I do some manipulation of your classes and a bit more, show how to select just those (which is your question). NOTE: if you click the second button a second time it gets the NEW first one...

```js
$(function() {
  $("#make-obvious-stuff").on('click', function() {
    // select by those with the style transform
    let these = $("[style='transform: scale(0.001)']");
    // now do some stuff with them
    // show how many:
    $(this).after("<div class='found'>Found:" + these.length + "</div>");
    // give class to first one
    these.first().addClass("make-obvious");
    // wrap those NOT the first one; see them do nothing
    these.not().first().wrap("<div class='wrapped'></div>");
    // does nothing:
    these.not().first().show(); // does nothing
    // remove the transform on first one: NOW we see it.
    these.first().css("transform", "");

  });

  $("#do-stuff").on('click', function() {
    // do what was asked: (but this does little perhaps?
    let these = $("[style='transform: scale(0.001)']");
    these.eq(0).addClass('itemPOS1');
    these.eq(1).addClass('itemPOS2');// this overrides the style with !important (that is a bad pattern to adopt)
    these.eq(2).addClass('itemPOS3');
    these.eq(4).addClass('itemPOS4');
  });
})
```

```css
.make-obvious {
  border: solid lime 1px;
  background-color: #ffdddd;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.wrapped: {
  border: solid blue 2px;
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: #ddffdd;
}

.found {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.itemPOS1 {
  background-color: #ddddff;
}
.itemPOS2 {
  background-color: #ffddff;
  transform: scale(1)!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>basic set</h2>
<div>Project 1</div>
<div>Project 2</div>
<div>Project 3</div>
<div>Project 4</div>
<div>Project 5</div>
<h2>test set filtered:</h2>
<div>Project 1</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 2</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 3</div>
<div>Project 4</div>
<div style="transform: scale(0.001)">Project 5</div>
Click me first:
<button id="do-stuff">Do Stuff</button> Click me Second:
<button id="make-obvious-stuff">Make Obvious</button>
```