# How can I distinguish between element not visible and not rendered?

Tags: javascript, dom, playwright, visible

I'm using Playwright for testing and need to differentiate between an element being hidden with CSS (via `display`, `visibility`, `opacity`, etc.) and an element not being rendered at all, meaning it's not part of the DOM.

In the Playwright documentation [toBeHidden](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-be-hidden), it states: "E*nsures that Locator either does not resolve to any DOM node, or resolves to a non-visible one.*"

```
const locator = page.locator('.my-element');
await expect(locator).toBeHidden();
```

From this test, I can't determine if `.my-element` is not rendered or simply hidden.

Is there a way in Playwright to distinguish between an element not being rendered and an element being hidden via CSS?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/133051/125981 and for older things like jQuery https://stackoverflow.com/q/17425543/125981

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is an optimal solution, but you can use:

```
await expect(loc).toBeAttached();
await expect(loc).toBeHidden();
```

if both of these pass — then it's hidden with CSS.

Also one could add a layer of abstraction, like:

```
await checkMyElementIsHiddenWithCss();

async function checkMyElementIsHiddenWithCss() {
  const locator = page.locator('.my-element');
  await Promise.all([
    expect(loc).toBeAttached(),
    expect(loc).toBeHidden(),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: You might want to clarify that the full assertion requires two steps: `await expect(loc).toBeAttached()` and `await expect(loc).toBeHidden()`.

Comment: I'm not even sure this is the optimal solution. I haven't used Playwright, expect in an isolated try case to check if it supports drag and drop, which Webdriver doesn't

Comment: It may not be optimal, but I tested it and it works on a simple example, and I'm not sure what better option there would be. So it's a good contribution for starters.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be some ambiguity about visibility in the answers posted so far. The question is actually pretty complex, and it's pretty easy to wind up with undesirable behavior.

Here's a runnable example to help figure out what's going on:

```js
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.39.0

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<p>normal</p>
<p style="visibility: hidden">hidden</p>
<p style="display: none">none</p>
</body></html>`;

test.beforeEach(({page}) => page.setContent(html));

test.describe("with two separate assertions: toBeHidden and toBeAttached", () => {
  test("an element with normal visibility fails", async ({page}) => {
    test.fail(); // this test should fail! the behavior is as expected.
    const loc = page.getByText("normal");
    await expect(loc).toBeHidden();
    await expect(loc).toBeAttached();
  });
  test("an element with visibility: hidden passes", async ({page}) => {
    const loc = page.getByText("hidden");
    await expect(loc).toBeHidden();
    await expect(loc).toBeAttached();
  });
  test("an element with display: none passes", async ({page}) => {
    const loc = page.getByText("none");
    await expect(loc).toBeHidden();
    await expect(loc).toBeAttached();
  });
  test("an element that does not exist fails", async ({page}) => {
    test.fail(); // this test should fail! the behavior is as expected.
    const loc = page.getByText("does not exist");
    await expect(loc).toBeHidden();
    await expect(loc).toBeAttached();
  });
});

test.describe("with one assertion: toBeVisible({visible: false})", () => {
  test("an element with normal visibility fails", async ({page}) => {
    test.fail(); // this test should fail! the behavior is as expected.
    const loc = page.getByText("normal");
    await expect(loc).toBeVisible({visible: false});
  });
  test("an element with visibility: hidden passes", async ({page}) => {
    const loc = page.getByText("hidden");
    await expect(loc).toBeVisible({visible: false});
  });
  test("an element with display: none passes", async ({page}) => {
    const loc = page.getByText("none");
    await expect(loc).toBeVisible({visible: false});
  });
  test("an element that does not exist passes (!)", async ({page}) => {
    // this passes but it's a false positive--the element doesn't exist
    const loc = page.getByText("does not exist");
    await expect(loc).toBeVisible({visible: false});
  });
});

test.describe("with one assertion: toBeHidden()", () => {
  test("an element with normal visibility fails", async ({page}) => {
    test.fail(); // this test should fail! the behavior is as expected.
    const loc = page.getByText("normal");
    await expect(loc).toBeHidden();
  });
  test("an element with visibility: hidden passes", async ({page}) => {
    const loc = page.getByText("hidden");
    await expect(loc).toBeHidden();
  });
  test("an element with display: none passes", async ({page}) => {
    const loc = page.getByText("none");
    await expect(loc).toBeHidden();
  });
  test("an element that does not exist passes (!)", async ({page}) => {
    // this passes but it's a false positive--the element doesn't exist
    const loc = page.getByText("does not exist");
    await expect(loc).toBeHidden();
  });
});
```

To summarize: only the dual assertion `toBeHidden()` and `toBeAttached()` captures both visible and invisible elements, with the caveat that it also considers `display: none` elements as attached. `.toBeHidden()` and `toBeVisible({visible: false})` have the same behavior on the tests here.

It's also possible to bake the visibility test into the locator, which helps avoid an assertion:

```js
test.describe("with :not(:visible) pseudoselector", () => {
  test("an element with normal visibility fails", async ({page}) => {
    test.fail(); // this test should fail! the behavior is as expected.
    const loc = page.locator(":text-is('normal'):not(:visible)");
    await expect(loc).toBeAttached();
  });
  test("an element with visibility: hidden passes", async ({page}) => {
    const loc = page.locator(":text-is('hidden'):not(:visible)");
    await expect(loc).toBeAttached();
  });
  test("an element with display: none passes", async ({page}) => {
    const loc = page.locator(":text-is('none'):not(:visible)");
    await expect(loc).toBeAttached();
  });
  test("an element that does not exist fails", async ({page}) => {
    test.fail(); // this test should fail! the behavior is as expected.
    const loc = page.locator(":text('does not exist'):not(:visible)");
    await expect(loc).toBeAttached();
  });
});
```

The behavior here is the same as the

```js
await expect(loc).toBeHidden();
await expect(loc).toBeAttached();
```

version (at least on the tests here).

If you want to also assert that the element does not have `display: none`, the only way I can think of doing it at the moment is `toHaveCSS`. I'll update this if there's a better way:

```js
test("an element with display: none fails", async ({page}) => {
  test.fail(); // this test should fail! the behavior is as expected.
  const loc = page.locator(":text-is('none'):not(:visible)");
  await expect(loc).toBeAttached();
  await expect(loc).not.toHaveCSS("display", "none");
});
```