# X-Editable not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, x-editable

X-Editable (bootstrap 2 version) is not working Chrome properly. When I click buttons, nothing changes (both save and discard changes). Looks like x-editable didn't respond to click event. What's more, console is not logging any errors. Works in firefox 25 and IE 10.

Tried to use normal and minified version.

Comment: Please post some code sample to demonstrate your problem to get timely help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found solution. It's related to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337186/jquery-isvisible-not-working-in-chrome) It turned out, that "if" with "is(':visible')" statement returns different values in Chrome and FF, so x-editable form is not hidding.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else having this issue, the !this.tip().is(':visible') was also failing for me. It turns out I had forgotten to include the bootstrap-editable.css file which has a display: inline-block; rule. Without this CSS Chrome reports the span as not being visible.
Copied from [enter link description here](https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/211)

Comment: This is correct and was the cause of my issues also. Thanks!