# X-editable click issue in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

Bootstrap version 3

X-editable inline mode is creating issue as the button click is not hiding the inline form if nothing has been changed in field. I see there are questions raised about it in past as mentioned below thread but they are 8 months old, so is this issue has been fixed in X-Editable plugin? if not then please guide if anyone has developed any custom fix for this so that inline mode can be used in chrome too. I prefer to have inline mode then Popup.

[X-Editable not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924989/x-editable-not-working-in-chrome?lq=1)

Thanks,
Amit Dangwal

Comment: I have not found any answer for this issue but a workaround is mentioned in post https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/issues/211. I have changed the code from
hide: function(reason) {

if(!this.tip() || !this.tip().is(':visible') || !this.$element.hasClass('editable-open')){
return;
}
to 
hide: function(reason) {

if(!this.$element.hasClass('editable-open')) {
return;
} it worked but I am not sure will it break any other part of code

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Turns out I was missing the bootstrap-editable.css file. Including this file fixed my problem.

See here
[X-Editable not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924989/x-editable-not-working-in-chrome).