# JQuery .on method not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I am using Jquery 2.1.0. I have injected some elements to the DOM (containing `label`) into a `div` element. I am using the following JavaScript to handle click event on all labels but it is completely dead and not responding. I checked and Jquery is loaded.

```
$('label').on("click", function () {
    var ul = $(this).parent().children("ul:first");
    if (ul.is(':visible')) {
        ul.css({ "display": "none" });
    }
    else {
       ul.css({ "display": "block" });
    }
});
```

I used developer tools in IE 10 and debugged the code. When I hit F5 it goes to my break point (on first line of my code) but when I click a `label` nothing happens and no errors.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Without event delegation you can only attach handlers to already injected elements (as the guy above pointed out) Also, use `.show()` and `.hide()`

Answer (score 2):

This will only assign the event handler to `label` elements which exist initially on the page:

```
$('label').on("click", function () {
  // ...
});
```

To catch elements which are added later, you need to assign the event handler to a common parent element (which isn't added/removed during the life of the page) and filter the source elements, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'label', function () {
  // ...
});
```

Note that there are *two* selectors:

- `document`
- `'label'`

The first, which is the target of the event handler, is only evaluated *once* when the page loads (or when this line of code is evaluated, which is generally when the page loads).  This attaches the handler to the `document` object.  Since all events "bubble up" to parent elements, this will catch *all* click events on the page (unless propagation is explicitly stopped, of course).

The second, which is the "filter" for the `.on()` method's handler, is evaluated any time an event is caught by this handler.  It filters out the elements which originated the `click` event so that the handler is executed only for those which match the filter.

I've actually [recently blogged](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/03/on-on-or-event-delegation-explained.html) about this very subject.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** since your label has been dynamically created element:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('body').on('click','label', function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Basically, event delegation will helps you to attach click event to newly added `label` elements in your case

Answer (score 1):

you should use [***event delegation***](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for that

```
$(document).on("click","label",function(){

});
```

Event delegation allows you to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector, whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

Answer (score 1):

From this answer to another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8337382/2407870

It seems that the method doesn't work for some inline elements in Chrome. If your element is inline, try changing the display to block.