# Array passed to ajax as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Why does Jquery UI Sortable `toArray` method give back array like this (in Firebug):

```
ordering[] = 1
ordering[] = 2
ordering[] = 3
```

And when i use custom function to ignore hidden items, it gives back a string, like this:

```
ordering = 1,2,3
```

I've checked plenty of times, it seems there's no difference between original Sortable `toArray` function code:

```
toArray: function(o) {
    var items = this._getItemsAsjQuery(o && o.connected),
        ret = [];
    o = o || {};
    items.each(function() { ret.push($(o.item || this).attr(o.attribute || "id") || ""); });
    return ret;
}
```

and my custom function:

```
function(){ // Do not pass hidden clones
    var items = [];
    $('#fp_parameters_list').children().each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) items.push($(this).attr('data-parameter-id'));
    });
    return items;
}
```

except that my doesn't counter hidden fields.

Thanks, if someone can help.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [jquery .is(“:visible”) not working in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337186/jquery-isvisible-not-working-in-chrome)?

Comment: I need to have order of sortable items sent by ajax, and i used toArray method before i needed to exclude hidden items from ordering. So i had to make custom function and it works fine, returning correct values, only problem is what's described in question: it returns it as a string, while toArray was returning array of ids. And it's strange as the functions are pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in other topic, i had to invoke the function to get correct result.
Here's the topic: [Function result array inside $.ajax is converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729429/function-result-array-inside-ajax-is-converted-to-string)

There's also one less code solution.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me:

HTML:

```
<div id="fp_parameters_list">
    <div data-parameter-id="3"></div>
    <div data-parameter-id="2"></div>
    <div data-parameter-id="10" style="display:none"></div>
    <div data-parameter-id="1"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
function mySort(){ // Do not pass hidden clones
    var items = [];
    $('#fp_parameters_list').children().each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {         
            items.push($(this).attr('data-parameter-id'));
        }
    });
    return items;
}

console.log(mySort()[0]);
```

[Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/dmann/vxLrN/2/)

Comment: Thanks for fiddle. Yes, it is working, but when i assign this function result to ajax data variable, it is transformed into a string of ids separated by comma.

Comment: While trying to show what i need, i found a strange thing: the result is passed as an array if function is declared outside $.ajax function, and it becomes string if i put it inside $.ajax. You can check the fiddle and compare how 2 requests are sending ordering in their post data.