# if element is visible do somethinf to another element

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

i am trying to `addClass` to another element if the element i am checking is visible, "have `display:block`" but nothing is happening,

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('.mejs-controls:visible')) {
            $('.mejs-captions-text').addClass('mejs-captions-text-move');
        }else{
            $('.mejs-captions-text').removeClass('mejs-captions-text-move');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are there multiple `.mejs-controls`?

Comment: Only one `.mejs-controls`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337186/jquery-isvisible-not-working-in-chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('.mejs-controls').is(':visible')) {
            $('.mejs-captions-text').addClass('mejs-captions-text-move');
        }else{
            $('.mejs-captions-text').removeClass('mejs-captions-text-move');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `if ($('.mejs-controls').is(':visible'))`