# How to check if the element is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i know if my `element` is visible or not using `javascript`. I'm using `$('#element').hide();`,     `$('#element').show();`  to hidden or shown an element. How can i check if the `element` is shown? The element is in the modal. I tried to change the element which is not in the modal and it worked, but when i put the element inside the modal it's not working..

I tried using this code but it's not working.

```
    <div class="well me">
         <label for="majore">Major Exam</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control majore" id="majore" oninput="total();"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <i class="fa fa-percent"></i>
             </span>
              </div>
     </div>

     <script>
            if ($('.me').is(':visible')) {                          
                  mt = m / 100 * 50 + 50;
                } 
    </script>
```

Comment: `$('#element').is(':visible')`

Comment: is majore a tagname?

Comment: @PranavCBalan i already tried that.. But it's not working.

Comment: Did you forget the `#`?

Comment: @nethken : can you reproduce the problem in snippet?

Comment: How do i put it in snippet?

Comment: Is the element a child (or descendant) of another element that is hidden?

Comment: I already add `#` it but still not working.

Comment: is major a class or id ?

Comment: I put all my code.

Comment: @nethken :  share your code in http://jsfiddle.net   or http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers  https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: or you can check if the element even exist to begin with maybe it doesnt exist

Comment: Give us your HTML code, edit your question with more code please

Comment: I edit my question guys. I'm trying to check if the `div` `.me` is visible or not.

Comment: scripts should be in a `script` tag. and you don't have an element with `me` class.

Comment: i copied and paste your code in snippet and its ok. this problem is cause by something else. im voting to close this OP

Comment: @nethken : Where are you hiding the elements ? I think the children is hidden here

Comment: @trincot the `if` is inside of the script tag.

Comment: OK, so you provide wrong information time and time again? Why don't you show it as it is? I am voting to close this. It is not clear.

Comment: @Pranav C Balan The children is visible sir. When i change the condition the computation is working.

Comment: @nethken :  the problem lies somewhere else... we can only identify if you were shared more code...

Comment: It is working !! just initialize the values of `mt & m `

Comment: @nethken :  be more clear about.... where are you hiding the element ? which element is hiding ?  ...

Comment: Guys, It's working when i change the element. The `div` is in the modal.

Comment: Please visit the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337186/jquery-isvisible-not-working-in-chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 "none" == document.getElementById("element").style.display //Check for hide

 "block" == document.getElementById("element").style.display //Check for show
```

you can use like also

```
  if ($('#element').css('display') == 'none') {
    alert('element is hidden');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checks for display:[none|block], ignores visible:[true|false]

```
$('#element').is(":visible");
```

Comment: #majore you for got the #

Answer (score 0):

It seems your selector is wrong.

Example of `$("[element]").is(":visible")` below: (for refrence)

```js
$("#show").on("click", function() {
  $("#text").show();
})
$("#hide").on("click", function() {
  $("#text").hide();
})
$("#getStatus").on("click", function() {
  alert($("#text").is(":visible"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">Hello</div>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="getStatus">Get Status</button>
```

Comment: My `div` im trying to check is in the modal sir.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.me')` is a class selector which will return `array` of `elements` where elements have class `me`.

So you need to target the specific `div` either by using `this` or by using `index` as there can be many `elements` with same `class name`.

`$('.me').is(':visible')` this will check the first element and return result according to first element's visibility.

You can try

```
$(".me").eq(1).is(':visible')    //Here 1 is index of div which can vary
```

OR

```
$(this).is(':visible')
```

Comment: Sir. The element im trying to check is in the modal. Is is the cause of the problem?

Comment: Modal is visible or not when you are trying to check this.